# Retrieving Google profile picture with Omniauth on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, omniauth

I'm starting a new Rails 3 app using Omniauth for authentication via Facebook, Twitter and Google. I can easily get the user's avatar from Facebook and Twitter, but can't find a way to retrieve it from Google, if existent.

Here's the code I use to build the authentication hash:

```
omniauth['user_info']['email'] ? @authhash[:email] =  omniauth['user_info']['email'] : @authhash[:email] = ''
omniauth['user_info']['name'] ? @authhash[:name] =  omniauth['user_info']['name'] : @authhash[:name] = ''
omniauth['uid'] ? @authhash[:uid] = omniauth['uid'].to_s : @authhash[:uid] = ''
omniauth['provider'] ? @authhash[:provider] = omniauth['provider'] : @authhash[:provider] = ''
```

On Twitter and Facebook this next line gets the avatar or sets to the default if not provided:

```
omniauth['user_info']['image'] ? @authhash[:image] =  omniauth['user_info']['image'] : @authhash[:image] = 'avatar.jpg'
```

This doesn't work on Google and I couldn't find any documentation on that.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: From the Omniauth documentation: "Google is very strict about keeping authorization and authentication separated. They give no endpoint to get a user's profile directly that I can find. We *can* get their name and email out of the contacts feed, however." So it looks like I won't be able to do that. Maybe only with Google+ integration.

Answer (score 7):

Try 'Omniauth Google OAuth2 Strategy' in which a commit states:

> Returns name, first_name, last_name, image, email in info with :scope => 'userinfo.email,userinfo.profile'

You can view the commit [here](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/pull/7)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I've abandoned Google login support at this project, so I won't be able to test if now Omniauth is  able to get the profile pictures. Being so, I can't accept your answer as correct, but I've upvoted it. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. Good luck with whichever solution you pursue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can get the picture, though i would imagine it depends on what versions your using.

im using

> rvm current
>       ruby-1.9.3-p194

```
> gem list
oauth (0.4.6)
oauth2 (0.8.0)
omniauth (1.1.0, 1.0.3)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1, 1.4.0)
omniauth-google (1.0.1)
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.1.13)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.0, 1.0.3)
omniauth-twitter (0.0.12)
```

I arrived here for a different reason that was due to the fact that the naming convention to access the profile properties was different from those explain in various tutorials, as such i was experiencing error completing the sign in. In fact in your question you may find that you will have the same issues.

The problem is that google has different property names from FB, Twitter, etc. so you have to account for that.

To find the properties i commented out the doing bit, and just dumped the response out.  like so.

```
elsif service_route == 'google_oauth2'
render :text => omniauth.to_yaml
return
```

This will output your google profile details which will hopefully look like the following.

```
--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
provider: google_oauth2
uid: '1234567'
info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash
  name: Your Name
  email: yourEmail
  first_name: firstname
  last_name: surname
  image: https://animage
credentials: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  token: aToken
  expires_at: 123
  expires: true
extra: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  raw_info: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    id: '123456'
    email: YourEmail
    verified_email: true
    name: YourName
    given_name: Name
    family_name: surname
    link: https://plus.google.com/blah
    picture: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/blah blah
    gender: male
    birthday: ''
    locale: en-GB
```

As you can see the names of the parameters are different, get rid of **user_info** and instead have **info**.

You will also notice that you have **picture:** and **image:** so whilst i have not tried this i would assume that it is your profile picture.

```
elsif service_route == 'google_oauth2'
    omniauth['info']['email'] ? email = omniauth['info']['email'] : email = ''
    omniauth['info']['name'] ? name = omniauth['info']['name'] : name = ''
    omniauth['uid'] ? uid = omniauth['uid'] : uid = ''
    omniauth['provider'] ? provider = omniauth['provider'] : provider = ''
    omniauth['info']['image'] ? image = omniauth['info']['image'] : image = ''
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, as I stated in the previous answer, I've abandoned Google login support for this project, so I won't be able to test your answer nor accept it as correct. I've upvoted it, though, and I'm sincerely grateful that you took the time to reply. All the best!

Comment: No problem. I'd literally just completed the omniauth tutorial (all of them out of date for the latest versions) and had to solve the above stated to get it to work. So Anyone reading this will essentially get the answer they would look for if they saw your question. Or at least be one step closer if the image wasn't the profile image (likewise i haven't tried it either).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found out that it was just that the image of the profile wasn't public. I had to change the settings from 'Visible only to people I can chat with' to 'Visible to everyone'. Then the image started to show up. Hope this helps someone.